# How to connect my finished java methods with graphics?

Tags: java, minesweeper

I am creating minesweeper game on Java, and have nearly finished all the methods, yet have never worked with graphics before. I would love to apply simple graphics to the methods such as a grid looking board representing the 2D array, and flags and bombs that may replace the characters i am working with now. I am not sure how to add these graphics to my already created methods. For instance, right now, I have an & sign representing bombs and # representing empty boxes.

Comment: You don't "add graphics to methods" but you build a user interface that uses those methods. You should have a look into some JavaFX or Swing tutorial to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how you can work with 2D

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class Dialog extends JFrame {

    JPanel panSouth;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton but;
    JTextField tf1;
    JTextField tf2;
    JTextField tf3;
    JTextField tf4;
    private int colorIndex = 0;
    Color color = Color.BLACK;

    public Dialog() {
        super("Graphics by Java: the cells drawing");
        setSize(700, 700);
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
            SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(this);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panSouth = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setColor(color);
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(Integer.parseInt(tf4.getText()))); 

                int bx = panSouth.getWidth();
                int by = panSouth.getHeight();
                int nx = Integer.parseInt(tf1.getText());
                int ny = Integer.parseInt(tf2.getText());
                int dx = Math.round( bx / nx);
                int dy = Math.round( by / ny);

                double an = Integer.parseInt(tf3.getText());
                g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(an));

                // OX
                int fromX;
                for (int i = -2*nx; i < nx * 2; i++) {
                    fromX = i * dx;
                    g2d.drawLine(fromX, -2*by, fromX, by*2);
                }

                // OX
                int fromY;
                for (int i = -2*ny; i < ny * 2; i++) {
                    fromY = i * dy;
                    g2d.drawLine(-2*bx, fromY, bx*2, fromY);
                }
            }

        };
        panel = new JPanel();
//        panel.setBackground(Color.PINK);
//        panSouth.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        tf1 = new JTextField(5);
        tf1.setText("25");
        tf2 = new JTextField(5);
        tf2.setText("15");
        tf3 = new JTextField(5);
        tf3.setText("0");
        tf4 = new JTextField(5);
        tf4.setText("1");
        but = new JButton("Change");
        panel.add(new JLabel("T: "));
        panel.add(tf4);
        panel.add(new JLabel("X: "));
        panel.add(tf1);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Y: "));
        panel.add(tf2);
        panel.add(new JLabel(" D: "));
        panel.add(tf3);
        panel.add(but);

        add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(panSouth, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        but.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }

        });

        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            //   @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                super.mouseClicked(e);
                colorIndex = colorIndex + 1;
                if (colorIndex > 2) {
                    colorIndex = 0;
                }
                switch (colorIndex) {

                    case 0:
                        color = Color.RED;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        color = Color.BLUE;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        color = Color.GREEN;
                        break;
                    default:
                        color = Color.RED;
                        break;
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Dialog().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here are some buttons and mouse listener where you can use to mark bombs.